# How to check subscription on app start?

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am really enjoying the development of Ionic 2 apps, but at the moment I have some problems with my purchase process.

How do I check, when the app starts, if the user has a valid purchase? 
I want to achieve the following behavior:

**User has subscription:** -> show PAGE A

**User doesn't have subscription:** -> show PAGE B

Do I have to save the subscription information locally?

** edit **

Iam using a firebase backend and could store the purchase there.

This is my function:

```
buyCoach(productName: string): void {
    console.log(productName);
    InAppPurchase
        .getProducts([productName])
        .then((products) => {
            InAppPurchase
                .buy(productName)
                .then((data)=> {
                    // {
                    //   transactionId: ...
                    //   receipt: ...
                    //   signature: ...
                    // }

                    // maybe store somethign to firebase? But what?
                })
                .catch((err)=> {
                    console.log("error buy");
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("error getProducts");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an Authentication and Authorisation solution. 
The user has to be identified (Authenticated) somehow. You don't need to implement yours and instead you can use Facebook, GooglePlus or Tweeter ones. You can use the Azure Mobile App services that allows your users to login to any of these three.

Once you do the above, you can securely call a service you have developed, let's say the user profile service, that tells you what subscriptions the user has.

You can store this information locally using [Ionic's Secure Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/secure-storage/) plugin for performance purposes

To navigate to another page you can use [NavController.push](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/) to navigate to pages.

Comment: Yes. User information and so login is needed here, for getting user's subscription. Whether to store this info **ONLY** locally is a bad idea. Store it in database linked to the user, so, when user logs in from any other platform/device, the subscription info will be there from database. `nav.push(PageA)` should be simple enough.

Comment: Sounds good, iam already using firebase in my ionic 2 app as a backend. 

But how do i check in an interval or something, if the user have still an active subscription?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got your question right, but you can do the following to check if the user is logged (beeing by email, facebook, google, etc.) and able to purchase:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) { // CREATES AN OBSERVABLE TO WATCH IF THE USER CHANGES IT STATES, LIKE LOGOFF
  if (user) { //
    this.rootPage = Page_A; // THE USER IS LOGGED, SHOW PAGE A
  } else {
    this.rootPage = Page_B; // USER NOT LOGGED, PAGE B
  }
});
```

If you're trying to know if the user has a purchase he hasn't finished when he left the app, you can do the following:

- Save the user id on you localStorage/SQLite.
- If the user doesn't has an account (if you want them to buy without beeing logged) use the firebase method `.push()` with the cart info, it'll generate a random key that you can grab in the promisse return using `.then()`.
- In your rootpage (both A and B) have a `ionViewWillLeave()` method that saves the current shop cart in his firebase node (using the saved uid).
- On app open you get the shop cart from firebase, if it exists, and the itens (prefer doing this on your rootPage with a `ionViewDidLoad()` or something like this, on `app.component`'s `deviceReady()` it could slow down your app a bit)
- Upon app exit, if the shop cart is empty, remove the shop cart node from database, if not, override the saved cart.

Try a database like:

```
/Users
|_ User_uid
   |_ User_Info_Node
   |  |_ USER_NAME //AND CITY, PHONE, ETC.
   |_ CART
      |_ CART_ITEM1_ID
      |_ CART_ITEM2_ID
      |_ CART_ITEM3_ID
```